# the hornetq libraries aren't loaded

Tags: java, jboss, hornetq

when I start my jboss I read in my console:

> HornetQAIO64 -> error loading the native library:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HornetQAIO64 in java.library.path
>
> no HornetQAIO in java.library.path
>
> no HornetQAIO32 in java.library.path

I download " source code" hornet from [here](https://hornetq.jboss.org/downloads)

I download the source end extract in folder. So I put in my "path environment system" the

in the `/bin` folder

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\***\***\jar\hornetq-HornetQ_2_4_0_Final\hornetq-HornetQ_2_4_0_Final\hornetq-native\bin
```

where there are these files:
[image]

The problem remains and the libraries are not loaded.Anyone can help me?

Comment: What platform are you running HornetQ on (e.g. Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

The HornetQ AIO integration only work on Linux since AIO is only available in Linux. You appear to be using Windows since your broker is in `C:\Users\...`.

Aside from that, the HornetQ code-base is no longer maintained since its [donation to the Apache ActiveMQ community](http://hornetq.blogspot.com/2015/06/hornetq-apache-donation-and-apache.html) 7 years ago. HornetQ is still open-source so you're free to fix any bugs you find and build your own release(s), but I **strongly** recommend you move to [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) which is based on the donated HornetQ code-base. The most recent release was less than a month ago.